# Missing Return Statement

Tags: java

I am trying to write code which would, given the time of day in terms of an hour, minute, second and "day half" (i.e., AM or PM), calculate and return the fraction of the day (a value of type double) that has elapsed since midnight (12:00 AM).

For example,

```
System.out.print(fractionOfDay(12, 0, 0, 'A'));
```

would print 0.0

```
System.out.print(fractionOfDay(12, 0, 0, 'P'));
```

would print 0.5

```
System.out.print(fractionOfDay(11, 59, 59, 'P'));
```

would print 0.999988426

I have written the following code:

```
public class FractionOfDay {
    public static double fractionOfDay(double h, double m, int s, char a ) {
        if (a == 'P' && h == 12) {
            double x = (h * 60 * 60) + (m * 60) + (s);
            double y = x / 86400;
            return y;
        } else if (a == 'P' && h != 12) {
            double x = ( (h + 12) * 60 * 60) + (m * 60) + (s);
            double y = x / 86400;
            return y;
        } else if (a == 'A' && h == 12) {
            double x = (m * 60) + (s);
            double y = x / 86400;
        } else if (a == 'A' && h != 12) {
            double x = ( (h) * 60 * 60) + (m * 60) + (s);
            double y = x / 86400;
            return y;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fractionOfDay(12, 0, 0, 'P'));
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile this code, it gives me the error

> missing return statement.

I don't understand what is wrong with the code.

Comment: What would `fractionOfDay(1.0, 1.0, 1, 'Q')` return?

Comment: @immibis what do you mean Q? there is only AM and PM?

Comment: you know that, but the computer doesn't. And what should happen if you decide to write it anyway?

Comment: @immibis so it would fail. So I should add an else statement? The problem is, I have tried. Whenever I put it, it still says missing return statement.

Comment: What did you put in the `else`?  It either needs to return something or throw an exception.  Otherwise the code could get to the end of the method without returning anything.  As long as the compiler thinks that can happen, it will not compile your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because all of your return statements are within if statements. Java sees this and judges that there is a possibility that none of these if statements will be taken. Then what would happen? There would be no return, so it spits out an error.

So you need to add a return statement under an else clause or outside of the if/else if block entirely. Something like this will solve your problem. You would have to figure out what to do when none of your paths gets taken. In this case it will return -1 (the default value of y)

```
 public class FractionOfDay {

    public static double fractionOfDay(double h, double m, int s, char a ) {
        double y = -1;
        if (a == 'P' && h == 12) {
            double x = (h * 60 * 60) + (m * 60) + (s);
             y = x / 86400;
        } else if (a == 'P' && h != 12) {
            double x = ( (h + 12) * 60 * 60) + (m * 60) + (s);
            y = x / 86400;
        } else if (a == 'A' && h == 12) {
            double x = (m * 60) + (s);
            y = x / 86400;
        } else if (a == 'A' && h != 12) {
            double x = ( (h) * 60 * 60) + (m * 60) + (s);
            y = x / 86400;
        }
        return y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fractionOfDay(12, 0, 0, 'P'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now about adding the else clause. Thanks. Do you have any idea if I can make the code better?

Comment: Usually, you want to limit the number of returns to one. Some cases require two, but really try to only have one way out of a function. So it would be better to return y at the end and only assign to it in the if statements.

Comment: @JDrost1818 disagree, that is a stylistic decision that should be up to the individual programmer (or the style guidelines they choose to follow).

Comment: @JDrost1818 I tried adding an else statement at the bottom of the if commands but it didn't change anything. It still says, there is a missing return statement

Comment: @immibis That's why I used "usually", but to a beginner, I would suggest trying to abide to it. It helps resolve issues like these.

Comment: @JDrost1818 I think this "one-exit" rule is something that used to be taught many years ago, but not any more.

Comment: @JDrost1818 Thanks for your help. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

The code doesn't tell you what to do in the case where `a` is something other than `'A'` or `'P'`.  Maybe *you* know it will never be anything else, but the compiler doesn't know that, so it believes there's a possibility that the code might hit the end of the method without returning anything, which is a no-no.

Since this is a public method, you really ought to have your code do something with cases when the arguments don't fit into one of your cases, since an outside class could screw up and call it with the wrong thing.  The obvious solution is to put a `throw` at the end of the method, something like

```
throw new RuntimeException("Invalid arguments to fractionOfDay");
```

This will prevent the error message from occurring.

Comment: Where should I put that exactly?

Comment: As the last statement of the method.